# Relating the definition of limits in metric space and topological space

Tags: general-topology

I have been given two definitions:

- A sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ in the metric space $\left(X,d\right)$ has a limit $a\in X$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
  $n>N\Rightarrow d\left(x_n,a\right)<\ \epsilon$
- A sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ converges to $x\in X$ if for each open set $U$ containing $a$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow x_n\in U$

I was wondering how I can prove that the two definitions are equivalent to each other. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the first definition implies the second:

Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the first sense.  Given an open set $U$ containing $x$, you need to show there exists an $N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$.

Since $U$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B$ of center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $U$.  Now by definition,

$$B = \{ y \in X : d(y,x) < \epsilon\}.$$

Since $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the first sense, there exists an $N$ such that $x_n \in B \subset U$ for all $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

Surely from a nested sequence of open sets you can get a sequence of points.  And surely from a decreasing sequence of "distances from the limit", you can get a nested sequence of open sets...  So first you need a strictly decreasing sequence of open ball radii = epsilons.